# jQuery - Shorthand for multiple identical IF conditions and simultaneously matched for several elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a shorter way of writing this for jQuery? Bundling it somehow? Seems awfully inefficient.

```
if (
   ($('#fname-field').val() == '')  || 
   ($('#lname-field').val() == '')  || 
   ($('#cell-field').val() == '')   || 
   ($('#email-field').val() == '')  || 
   ($('#street-field').val() == '') || 
   ($('#pcode-field').val() == '')  || 
   ($('#city-field').val() == '')   || 
) { // Do something }
```

I have searched around but haven't found an answer yet. I don't think the following is equivalent:

```
if ($('#fname-field, #lname-field, #cell-field etc...' == '')) { // Do something }
```

It's not equivalent since it doesn't run the conditions as a group, instead individually? Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give all the elements that you want to validate a class and then use jQuery's each function

```
$('.validate').each(function(index) {
  if ($(this).val() == '')
     alert("empty");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Or if you just want an alert once do:

```
$('.validate').each(function(index) {
  if ($(this).val() == ''){
     alert("empty");
     return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Something like `$('input.validate[value=]').length`

Comment: Ok. I am probably wrong, but wouldn't that run each .validate element individually. So lets say 2 of 7 elements are == '' then this solution would do alert("empty") 2 times? Right? Wrong? Can I do all the checks simultaneously and always run the "// Do something" once if one or more elements == '' without checking if "// Do something" has been run before?

Comment: I updated the answer. Alternatively you could set a variable in the if condition and check it after with another if condition but that would be more difficult than your initial code :)

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. A couple of additional follow-up questions (due to my limited experience): 1) In the first code snippet you provide, is there a curly bracket missing for the IF statement? 2) How come the second code snippet only returns "empty" once, is it because the "return false" breaks the execution of the function? The function doesn't run for each .validate element (i.e. many times)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this..

```
if ($('#fname-field, #lname-field, #cell-field/*, ..*/')
    .filter(function () { 
         return $(this).val(); 
     }).length)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i  = 0; 
$('input').each(function() { 
if($(this).val().length == '0') { 
i++;; 
}  
});
alert("Found " + i + " empty fields");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QrkWz/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach

```
var isCheck = false;
 var elems = $('#fname-field ,#lname-field , #cell-field , #email-field ,#street-field ,#pcode-field , #city-field' );
        $.each(elems , function() {
            if($this).val() == ''){
               isCheck = true;
               return false
            }
        });

        if(isCheck){
           // Your code here
        }
        else{
          //  Do something else
        }
```